# <div> tags working in Chrome, but not in Firefox/IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, tags

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <!-- META -->
        <title>Nina Rakovec</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Profesionalna igralka" />

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

    </head>

    <body>

            <div class="image"></div>
            <a href="http://www.ninarakovec.com/eng/"><div class="eng"></div></a>
            <a href="http://www.ninarakovec.com/slo/"><div class="slo"></div></a>

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
  background: url("ninabg.jpg") left top no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

div.image {
    overflow: hidden;
    content:url("logo2fix.png");
    position:absolute;
    right:1%;
    bottom:3%;
    height:40%;
    width:35%;
}

div.slo {
    content:url("slo.png");
    position:absolute;
    width:5%;
    bottom:10%;
    right:21%;
}

div.eng {
    content:url("eng.png");
    position:absolute;
    width:5%;
    right:12%;
    bottom:10%
}
```

This is the code and it is showing properly in Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer or Firefox. What am I doing wrong? The only thing that's showing is the background, the 3 div tags are not showing up and I have no idea why.
Thanks in advance, I need this fixed and I'm clueless.

Comment: Try dropping the "div" from your CSS.  It's not necessary.

Comment: Oh, I thought you had to write div all the time, thanks for that, but sadly it did not help.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `content' property to display images like that. It's intended for use with pseudo-elements. If those divs need bg images use the background-image property. You say the divs aren't showing up...what happens if you put a border on them?

Comment: Thanks so much Paulie_D, this is working now! :) I had no idea that the content property wasn't intended for images.

Comment: @Paulie_D Looks like your suggestion fixed the issue. You should write it up in an answer for the OP to accept. I'll upvote it as well.

Comment: I still have a problem, I can't seem to find a solution how to make my <div> into a link.. anyone? :(

Comment: Thanks all. Placed as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `content' property to display images like that. It's intended for use with pseudo-elements.

If those divs need bg images use the background-image property.

```
div.image {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image::url("logo2fix.png");
    position:absolute;
    right:1%;
    bottom:3%;
    height:40%;
    width:35%;
}

div.slo {
    background-image::url("slo.png");
    position:absolute;
    width:5%;
    bottom:10%;
    right:21%;
}

div.eng {
    background-image:url("eng.png");
    position:absolute;
    width:5%;
    right:12%;
    bottom:10%
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In HTML 4.01, it is not valid markup to have a `<div>` element inside an `<a>`. According to the spec, `<a>` tags can only contain inline elements. `<div>`'s are block level elements. Note that it is up to each browser on how they handle such situations. While Chrome may fix the content or render it in the method you desire, it's entirely possible Firefox and IE would view it as completely invalid and fail to render some or all of the markup (or strip the div tags out and leave the content intact).

See this question for further reference: [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct#answer-1828032).

**Reference:** [HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-A)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you can see that the first <div class="image"></div> element doesn't have <a> tags and it still isn't working so I am not sure what I am supposed to do now.

Comment: Which part is not working? Does the element not render or is it empty with no picture?

Comment: The element didn't render, but I fixed this by changing my css from content to background-image property.